# Optimize non-layered files in dojo build

Tags: dojo

How do I tell the dojo build system to run the shrinksafe optimization on files NOT included  in a layer but in the perfixes directories?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are [two optimization parameters for custom builds](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-4-meta-dojo/package-system-and-custom-builds): `optimize` and `layerOptimize`. In your case, you would need to set `optimize=shrinksafe`.

- **optimize** Specifies how to optimize module files. If "comments"
  is specified, then code comments are
  stripped. If "shrinksafe" is
  specified, then the Dojo compressor
  will be used on the files, and line
  returns will be removed. If
  "shrinksafe.keepLines" is specified,
  then the Dojo compressor will be used
  on the files, and line returns will
  be preserved. If "packer" is
  specified, Then Dean Edwards' Packer
  will be used Default: "",
- **layerOptimize** Specifies how to optimize the layer files. If
  "comments" is specified, then code
  comments are stripped. If
  "shrinksafe" is specified, then the
  Dojo compressor will be used on the
  files, and line returns will be
  removed. If "shrinksafe.keepLines" is
  specified, then the Dojo compressor
  will be used on the layer files, and
  line returns will be preserved. If
  "packer" is specified, Then Dean Edwards' Packer will be used Default: "shrinksafe",

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the folder that contains the files to optimise as a package in the build profile so that it can be optimised.

```
packages: [
{
    name:"dojo",
    location:"dojo"
},
{
    name:"filesToOptimise",
    location:"folderLocation"
}
]
```

Make sure you have a profile.js and package.json in that directory and `optimize:"shrinksafe"` option in your build profile as well.